# Convert Big Integer value to eight bit bytes(2s complement big endian) sequence which is multiple of 8 in Java

Tags: java, java-8, biginteger, data-conversion, kmip

How to convert [big integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) to the following **byte array** form in Java:

Big Integers are encoded as a sequence of eight-bit bytes, in two's complement notation, transmitted big-endian. If the length of the sequence is not a multiple of eight bytes, then Big Integers SHALL be padded with the minimal number of leading sign-extended bytes to make the length a multiple of eight bytes.

This is to be in terms with [KMIP protocol](http://docs.oasis-open.org/kmip/spec/v1.1/os/kmip-spec-v1.1-os.html), section 9.1.1.4 Item Value

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no padding functionality provided by the `BigInteger` API, so you have to do the padding yourself:

For a `BigInteger bigInt`, use

```
byte[] array = bigInt.toByteArray();
int len = array.length, len8 = len+7 & ~7;
if(len != len8) {
    int pad = len8 - len;
    byte[] nArray = new byte[len8];
    if(bigInt.signum() < 0) Arrays.fill(nArray, 0, pad, (byte)-1);
    System.arraycopy(array, 0, nArray, pad, len);
    array = nArray;
}
```

- First, use `toByteArray()` to get a byte array
- calculate the next multiple of eight for the array length
- If this number is not identical to the length, you need padding

  - allocate an array of the required size
  - fill the padding with `-1` (sign extension) when negative (it already has the required zeros in the other case)
  - copy the original bytes

Note that a sign extended padded array still is compatible to the `BigInteger(byte[])` constructor, so an `assert bigInt.equals(new BigInteger(array));` after the operation should never fail.